Patterns to handle large transactions in dynamodb?
So I got a fairly simple table:
attributeSchema: [{AttributeName: "pk", AttributeType: "S"}, {AttributeName: "sk", AttributeType: "N"}]
keySchema: [{AttributeName: "pk", KeyType: "HASH"}, {AttributeName: "sk", KeyType: "RANGE"]
otherAttributes: attr1 (bool), attr2(number)

table: 
| pk       | sk      | attr1 | attr2 |
--------------------------------------
| pk1      | 0       | ...   |       |
| pk1      | ...     | ...   |       |  
| pk1      | 200     | ...   |       |
| pk2      | 0       | ...   |       |
| pk2      | 200     | ...   |       |

There's a case where we want to delete all rows of a pk partition (i.e pk = pk1) and then add a bunch of new entries back into the partition. With the current data model this operation won't fit into a single transaction (max 100 items), which I would like for atomicity and rollback.
Solution 1:
One easy way around this I thought of was to just collapse the data model to something like
attributeSchema: [{AttributeName: "pk", AttributeType: "S"}]
keySchema: [{AttributeName: "pk", KeyType: "HASH"}]


| (pk)     | byteAttr
-------------------
| pk1      |   ...   
| pk2      |   ....

Essentially, get rid of the range/sort key altogether and marshall all records for a pk into a json object or something, keyed by the sk. This means offloading more work to marshalling/unmarshalling
Solution 2:
| pk | clearingLock |


For every Put operation that's not put of this clear-then-write operation, wrap it in a Transaction with a ConditionCheck that clearinglock is off for that pk.
However, this does not offer any automatic rollback if any of the transaction batches fail.
